# sequence\ flow analysis with score- beginner data scientist

Tags: python, modeling

I'm trying to create a model that will give me the best parts that lead to a maximized score out of a sequence.

my data(spark rdd) looks like this:

("dan", "john", "john", "guy", 45)

("john", "dan", "guy", 60)

("guy", "guy", "guy", "guy", "guy", "guy", "guy", "guy" 8)

("guy", "john", "john", "guy", "mark", 0)

- the number of names is known, and finite.
- the length of the longest sequence is also known and finite.
- the sequence is by order of appearance, with the score being the outcome.
- i also have the data of the specific time stamp when each occurrence happens.

I'm trying to find the best combination/ the best parts that will maximize my final score,(so i can say "john" is crucial to getting a high score, but 'guy" is not very effective)

any help will be extremely appreciated,
thanks in advance!